# Sharepoint 2013 Search Keyword Query Language (KQL) field value is null or empty

Tags: search, 2013

I have a search query, in which I want certain a field to return results where its value is empty :

```
(contentclass:sts_listitem OR IsDocument:True) SPSiteUrl:http://sharepoint2013b:41000/sites/Catalog ListId:e56dfdd7-4f96-4fa5-b4d5-da75fd56aefd (wstaxidMetadataRegion:**EMPTY**)
```

How do I do that? Could not see any option from : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx

Comment: Do you find any solution ? I search similar query like (`StartDate>={Today}` or `StartDate:EMPTY`)

Comment: No, I just added a default value for my field(that cannot be any possible value for that field in real scenario) and checked with that.

Comment: Same problem here I want to have (PublishingStartDate <= {Today} OR PublishingStartDate:EMPTY).

Answer (score 4):

Agnes Molnar has your answer.

http://www.itunity.com/article/filter-empty-values-search-693

For example, I wanted to exclude all expired items without excluding items that have no expiration date.

So based on the referenced example, I added:

```
-ExpirationTime:1900-01-01..{Today-1}
```

So any result that does have an expiration date, and whose expiration date is less than today, does not get returned.

Answer (score 3):

Something based off whats here already, but put together fully for how I needed it and in case anyone else needs this.

Where a `start date` is blank or before `now` and an `end date` is blank or after `now` is as follows.

```
-EndDate:1900-01-01..{Today} -StartDate:{Today}..3000-12-31
```

Answer (score 2):

The only option I found was to do a search as so:

`NOT (MetadataProperty:"ABC" OR MetadataProperty:"DEF" OR MetadataProperty:"GHI")` and send it Search Query JSON using `window.location.href` or entering it in the search box

```
http://MyServer/site/Searchpage.aspx?Default={"k":"NOT (MetadataProperty:\"ABC\" OR MetadataProperty:\"DEF\" OR MetadataProperty:\"GHI\")","r":[]}
```